# How to change color of selection in Select2 4.0.1?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2

Hello i'm trying to figure out how to change the color of the selection (only if selected by user, placeholder has to be in default color - white) with select2 4.0.1

this is how it should look like in default, 3rd pic (first two are selected)
[image]

and after selection it should look like :
[image]

I know how to set CSS for select2 3.5.x but recently we've decided to update our select 2 and i'm struggling ...

original CSS for select2

```
.select2-container .select2-choice:not(.select2-default) {
background-image: none;
background-color: #D9FFC7;}
```

anyone? thanks for reply

[working jsfiddle](http:////jsfiddle.net/e4ozt5ra/14/)

Comment: added working jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you just have to add an !important to the background-image property, or make sure your custom CSS is included in your page after you include the select2 CSS.

```
.select2-container .select2-choice:not(.select2-default) {
    background-image: none !important;
    background-color: #D9FFC7;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Ok, looks like your JSFiddle was using the previous version of select2 when I was editing it. Now I see your problem.

Trying to stick with a pure CSS solution, I have come up with this:

```
.select2-selection {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.select2-selection__rendered[title] {
    background-color: #D9FFC7;
}
```

This will target the element that updates when you make a selection - a `title` attribute gets added to the `.select2-selection__rendered` element when you choose an option from the dropdown, so the above CSS will change the background colour when there is a `title` attribute present.

The `overflow: hidden` property is in there because when you change the background colour of that element, it spills out of the parent's element.

The flaw in this set up is that if you clear the selection, the `title` attribute stays there with the last option you had selected, meaning the field is left with the background coloured.

Comment: Sorry for being kinda rude (frustrated by not knowing how to fix if), your solution works nicely, that [title] wouldn't come to my mind, didn't know that there is this workaround about titles, but i knew i have to include the title to CSS :) thanks mate

Comment: No problem, I know the feeling! It's a shame the title attribute stays there when you clear the selection, otherwise this would work perfectly. You'll have to use JS to get around that.

Comment: Still a good solution for last version 4.0.4 : https://jsfiddle.net/Bouillou/kez86keb/3/